# Relative access to table cells using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, cell

I have a nested table 3x3

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td id='myCell'></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, i need to get cells closed to my '#myCell' - on the left, on the right, top, bottom.

```
var myCell = $('#myCell')[0];
var leftCell = myCell.previousSibling;
var rightCell = myCell.nextSibling;
var topCell = $(myCell).parent()[0].previousSibling().children()[myCell.cellIndex];
var bottomCell = $(myCell).parent()[0].nextSibling().children()[myCell.cellIndex];
```

It seems that is ok.
Now i need get the same cells with specefic table layout.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=3></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='myCell'></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This layout implies that I could get top, right, bottom cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct solution. I've used projection matrix to calculate near cells.
My solution released in [GridWizard - HTML Table Constructor](http://gridwizard.rayz.ru/)

Answer (score 1):

you may try defining special functions for retrieving each possible sibling cell

```
var myCell = $('#myCell');

function getLeft() {
  return $(myCell).previousSibling();
}

function getRight() {
  return $(myCell).nextSibling();
}
// etc for top/right
```

and on missing cells you'll just receive null;

Comment: I understood, how can i get right/left cells.
But this kind of code doesn't works when i try get bottom cell with the table cell with rowspan=3 on the begining.

cellIndex property of the middle cell is 0;

Comment: wouldn't it be `.prev()` and `.next()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, tr's and td's are unreliable when dealing with colspan/rowspan issues.  [SO1303106](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303106/1303404#1303404) shows a solution that builds up a matrix of each row/column and creates some functions to help you query it.  [This article](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/temp/table%5Fcellindex.html) inspired that solution, and shows the problem.  The solution is not jQuery specific, and I wouldn't be surprised if someone comes up with a better solution.

Comment: Thank you! i guessed that it's impossible. Already resolved that with the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I came accorss this question looking for something slightly different. Perhaps this will help. Given the following table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td id='selectMe'>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using JQuery:

```
$.('td#selectMe').prev('td'); //10
$.('td#selectMe').parent().next('td'); //30
```

Hope this provides another option and insight.